# How to continuously update an image using Flask and AJAX

Tags: javascript, python, html, ajax, flask

I want to implement a dashboard-style local webpage. There should be some images there that update dynamically (without having to refresh the webpage). For example, there should be an image of a car with closed doors and one with open doors. As events are triggered somewhere else in the server, I want the image to update.

I intended to do this through a polling approach, where the page refreshes the image every second with AJAX, and the Flask engine determines which image should be shown. **Is there a better way to do this?**

My current code has this in my HTML page. It is just a div container for the image and a script to load the image from a Flask call.

```
<div id="car_img" style="width:400px;height:400px;background:yellow"></div>

<script>
  setInterval(function(){
    $('#car_img').load($SCRIPT_ROOT + '/_curr_car_image');
  }, 2000) /* time in milliseconds (ie 2 seconds)*
</script>
```

In my Flask python script, I have the call, atm simply returning a single string with the image directory.

```
@app.route('/_curr_car_image')
def curr_car_image():
    # some logic here where the proper image would be selected
    return '/car_pics/car1.jpg'
```

If I access `http://127.0.0.1:5000/_curr_car_image`, I see the string proper, but maybe I need to channel it into a `src` attribute of an HTML image? Or maybe I should return HTML code? I'm really not sure what to do here.

So, what am I doing wrong here? This is just for a 5m demo, there is no need to do something fancy or fast, just something that works and we can use for the demo.